# ATLAS on ARM configuration failure

Tags: configuration, arm, atlas

I'm trying to install the ATLAS library (v3.10.1) on my Tegra3 ARM CPU (cortex-a9) under an Ubuntu 11.04 OS but I cannot passed the configuration step..
When I launch the "./configure" executable I get this following output:

```
make: `xconfig' is up to date.
./xconfig -d s /home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build/.././ -d b /home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build  -D c -DATL_ARM_HARDFP=1 -Ss ADdir /Libraries/ATLAS/build/ARMHARDFP -Si archdef 0 -Fa alg -mfloat-abi=hard

OS configured as Linux (1)

Assembly configured as GAS_ARM (7)

Vector ISA Extension configured as  NEON (10,1024)

Architecture configured as  ARMv7 (46)

Bad CPU MHZ value=0, res='CPU MHZ=0
'

Clock rate configured as 0Mhz

Maximum number of threads configured as  4
Parallel make command configured as '$(MAKE) -j 4'

Pointer width configured as 32
Cannot detect CPU throttling.
rm -f config1.out
make atlas_run atldir=/home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build exe=xprobe_comp redir=config1.out \
                args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 46 -Si nof77 0 -V 1024  -Fa ic '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa sm '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa dm '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa sk '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa dk '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa xc '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa gc '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa if '-mfloat-abi=hard' -b 32 -d b /home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build"
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build'
cd /home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build ; ./xprobe_comp -v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 46 -Si nof77 0 -V 1024  -Fa ic '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa sm '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa dm '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa sk '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa dk '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa xc '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa gc '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa if '-mfloat-abi=hard' -b 32 -d b /home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build > config1.out
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
/usr/bin/ld: error: /tmp/cck4AYUv.o uses VFP register arguments, xctest does not
/usr/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /tmp/cck4AYUv.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [IRunCComp] Error 1
/usr/bin/ld: error: /tmp/ccuMjBW4.o uses VFP register arguments, xctest does not
/usr/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /tmp/ccuMjBW4.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [IRunCComp] Error 1


Unable to find usable compiler for ICC; abortingMake sure compilers are in your path, and specify good compilers to configure
(see INSTALL.txt or 'configure --help' for details)make[1]: *** [atlas_run] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build'
make: *** [IRun_comp] Error 2
ERROR 512 IN SYSCMND: 'make IRun_comp args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 46 -Si nof77 0 -V 1024  -Fa ic '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa sm '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa dm '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa sk '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa dk '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa xc '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa gc '-mfloat-abi=hard' -Fa if '-mfloat-abi=hard' -b 32"'
mkdir src bin tune interfaces
mkdir: cannot create directory `src': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `bin': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `tune': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `interfaces': File exists
make: *** [make_subdirs] Error 1
make -f Make.top startup
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build'
Make.top:1: Make.inc: No such file or directory
Make.top:325: warning: overriding commands for target `/AtlasTest'
Make.top:76: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/AtlasTest'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Make.inc'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/Libraries/ATLAS/build'
make: *** [startup] Error 2
mv: cannot stat `lib/Makefile': No such file or directory
.././configure: 450: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
.././configure: 451: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
.././configure: 452: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
.././configure: 453: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
.././configure: 509: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
DONE configure
```

So, I have three questions:

First: Why "**Bad CPU MHZ value=0, res='CPU MHZ=0**" ? I precise that the CPU throttling of all the cores is set on 0 (I checked the /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/throttle files). Is there a way to pass the clock frequency of the ARM cpu as argument ?

Second: Why "**sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution**" ?

Third: "**Unable to find usable compiler for ICC; abortingMake..**" Is there a way to say at the ./configure executable to not looking for ICC ? Because I'm trying to build ATLAS on ARM therefore ICC is not available.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Guix

Answer (score 2):

The ATLAS configuration environment is broken for ARM, and not very fault tolerant in general:

- first it attempts to determine system performance by grepping in /proc/cpuinfo (which has never been intended for anything other than some human-readable information dump). You can override this by specifying a frequency on the configure command line: `-m <MHz>`
- then it probes for whether power management is enabled - if it is, it bails out again. Can't see a configure option, but if you make `ProbeThrottle()` in `CONFIG/src/backend/archinfo_linux.c` return 0, it gets past that.
- You're then hit by the fact that there seems to have actually been some work done for some Cortex-A8 platform several years ago, and the compiler flags set by default for ARMv7 in `CONFIG/src/atlcomp.txt` include `-mfloat-abi=softfp`. Change this to 'hard' and it will actually work on a modern ARM Linux distribution.
- The syntax error is fallout from trying to look for compilers in `/opt/bin` and `/opt/sbin` and not handling errors.

With the above workarounds, I don't see any ICC errors, and the build gets a fair bit along before crashing and burning.

In short, there will be some porting effort required in order for it to work properly on ARM. Maybe you can start by sending an error report to their developer mailing list?

Comment: http://www.vesperix.com/arm/index.html may be a potential alternative resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try these tricks and let you know.

Comment: I tried yours tricks (-m option, -mfloat-abi=hard was already done) but have exactly the same output as previously. Here is my cmd line: `../configure -D c -m=1300 -DATL_ARM_HARDFP=1 -Ss ADdir=/libraries/ATLAS/build/ARMHARDFP -Si archdef 0 -Fa alg -mfloat-abi=hard`

Comment: And I also tried ATLAS-ARM but I get many more errors at config: `Bad ASM`,`Bad VECTFLAG`, `Bad MACHTYPE`, ... etc. I'll send my question to the ATLAS technical support.